# All possible ways to arrange numbers into groups

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a set of 500 unique numbers.

How many unique groups comprising exactly 250 numbers each can I pick out of these 500?

The order of numbers in a group doesn't matter - a group `[1, 2, 3]` is considered the same as `[3, 1, 2]`.

I am confused here because the intuition is:

$$x = \frac{500!}{250!(500-250)!}$$

But I am not sure whether this takes into account the fact that `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 1, 2]` are not considered as distinct groups - they should be treated as the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the order of the group doesn't matter, it is simply 500C250.

When the order of the group matters it is 500C250 * 250! (or simply 500P250) since you've to consider all the arrangements possible within that 250 member group.

So, you're right!!